# return several values with autocb in iced coffee script

Tags: iced-coffeescript

How to return couple values in `iced coffee script` using `return` and `autocb`?

Without `autocb` I can do:

```
func = (cb)=>
   cb returnVal1, returnVal2
```

How to implement this using `autocb`? This code ...

```
func = (autocb)=>
   return returnVal1, returnVal2
```

... throws error:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected ,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error because you can't return more than one value in JavaScript. You could wrap the two values in an array and destructure it after calling...

```
func = (autocb)=>
   return [returnVal1, returnVal2] 

await func defer(returnVals)
[returnVal1, returnVal2] = returnVals
```

...but you should probably just use your first example. `autocb` is simple syntactical sugar (one argument instead of one line), and not at all necessary to using IcedCoffeeScript.

Answer (score 0):

Destructuring will work as mentioned here: https://github.com/maxtaco/coffee-script/issues/29

```
func = (thing, autocb) ->
   thing1 = doSomething(thing)
   thing2 = doSomethingElse(thing)

   {thing1, thing2}


await funct thing, defer {thing1, thing2}

console.log "#{thing1} and #{thing2}"
```

Comment: `ICED warning: overused deferral at <anonymous>` on line `autocb thing1, thing2` - is because of autocb returns automatically, so in fact your return 2 times

Comment: You're absolutely right. The JS that gets generated from what I was suggesting is autocb(autocb(thing1, thing2)). The answer is destructuring as I found here: https://github.com/maxtaco/coffee-script/issues/29